# no medication treatments for MS

Tags: mental-health, treatment, neurology, immune-system, treatment-options

> What are the no-medication treatments for Multiple sclerosis (MS) ?

Based on many papers, sport and meditation can help to keep the immune system and the body healthier which leads to a higher level of physical and mental health. Is there any specific method (without taking medications) for MS?

Comment: Just to clarify since you are mentioning the immune system, MS stands for *multiple sclerosis* and not *metabolic syndrome*? Also, you mention papers on the subject, citing or linking at least one that correlates the immune system functioning with sport and/or meditation would be a great help. Thanks! (I, personally, am not aware of any such method if we are talking about the first diagnosis, but if you provide some reliable papers on your part I would be willing to look further into it, it is a very interesting question).